# Can you fix my Ctrl+Left Ctrl+Shift+Left script?

Tags: windows, autohotkey, auto

It's only slightly not like I wanted it. It works fine, but if I want to hold down the functions it will perform actions once and add numbers instead of repeating the function. I wanted something to speed up the process of Ctrl+left arrow, and Ctrl+shift+left arrow, and Ctrl+Right Arrow & Ctrl+Shift+Right Arrow so that I can work with text faster.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VNRCQx0eWA0
You can view an example of what I am referring to here, and what's going wrong. I've marked the mistakes within the title of the video.

### script.ahk script contents

```
^1::
Send ^{Left Down}^{Left Down}
return
^2::
Send ^{Left Down}^{Left Down}^{Left Down}
return
^3::
Send ^{Left Down}^{Left Down}^{Left Down}^{Left Down}
return
^4::
Send ^{Left Down}^{Left Down}^{Left Down}^{Left Down}^{Left Down}
return
^5::
Send ^{Left Down}^{Left Down}^{Left Down}^{Left Down}^{Left Down}^{Left Down}
return
^6::
Send ^{Right Down}^{Right Down}
return
^7::
Send ^{Right Down}^{Right Down}^{Right Down}
return
^8::
Send ^{Right Down}^{Right Down}^{Right Down}^{Right Down}
return
^9::
Send ^{Right Down}^{Right Down}^{Right Down}^{Right Down}^{Right Down}
return
^0::
Send ^{Right Down}^{Right Down}^{Right Down}^{Right Down}^{Right Down}^{Right Down}
return
^+1::
Send ^+{Left Down}^+{Left Down}
return
^+2::
Send ^+{Left Down}^+{Left Down}^+{Left Down}
return
^+3::
Send ^+{Left Down}^+{Left Down}^+{Left Down}^+{Left Down}
return
^+4::
Send ^+{Left Down}^+{Left Down}^+{Left Down}^+{Left Down}^+{Left Down}
return
^+5::
Send ^+{Left Down}^+{Left Down}^+{Left Down}^+{Left Down}^+{Left Down}^+{Left Down}
return
^+6::
Send ^+{Right Down}^+{Right Down}
return
^+7::
Send ^+{Right Down}^+{Right Down}^+{Right Down}
return
^+8::
Send ^+{Right Down}^+{Right Down}^+{Right Down}^+{Right Down}
return
^+9::
Send ^+{Right Down}^+{Right Down}^+{Right Down}^+{Right Down}^+{Right Down}
return
^+0::
Send ^+{Right Down}^+{Right Down}^+{Right Down}^+{Right Down}^+{Right Down}^+{Right Down}
return
#q::exitApp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Keys := ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"]
for each, key in Keys
{
    Hotkey, ^%key%, Ctrl_Key, On 
    Hotkey, ^+%key%, Ctrl_Key, On
}
return

Ctrl_Key:
    last_Key := ""
    Index := ""
    last_Key := SubStr(A_ThisHotkey, 0)
    If (last_Key = 0)
        Index = 5
    else
    If (last_Key < 6)
        Index := last_Key + 1
    else
        Index := last_Key - 4
    Loop %Index%
    {
        If (last_Key < 6) and (last_Key > 0)
        {
            If GetKeyState("Shift","P")
                Send +^{Left}
            else
                Send ^{Left}
        }
        else
        {
            If GetKeyState("Shift","P")
                Send +^{Right}
            else
                Send ^{Right}
        }
    }
    ; Don't repeat the action before key is released: 
    KeyWait, %last_Key%
return
```

See [For-Loop](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/For.htm), [Hotkey](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Hotkey.htm) and [SubStr](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SubStr.htm) in the documentation and feel free to ask if you don't understand something.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I tried this code, but got the same results when I hold down the Ctrl+number combo, it performs the desired action, then constantly repeats the Number pressed vs. repeating the desired action.

Comment: See the edited answer (If I understand you correctly).

Comment: It works perfect, Thanks, I truly appreciate it, also thanks for linking the parts of manual that you used.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `down` from all commands. Correct syntax is:

```
^1::
    send ^{left}
return
```

To make repetitions you can write a number inside figure brackets, e.g. to repeat selection 5 times:

```
^+5::
    send ^+{right 5}
return
```